# how to fix a bug of sirius/viewpoint specification project

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-sirius

I'm using Sirius framework on eclipse mars (4.5).

When I create a new "viewpoint specification project" in class Activator appears this error:

"The type org.eclipse.core.resources.IResourceChangeListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Anybody has seen this problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanx a lot

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446111 which corresponds to this issue, and contains a workaround until we fix the core issue in Sirius itself.